# Requesting UX recommendations for multiple business objects creation in a flow

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, visual-flows

We have a requirement to implement a wizard (Salesforce flow) for creating multiple records of a business object. There are about 7 fields that are needed to be entered differently for these objects while the other fields have common values.
Also, the user will input the number of records that are needed to be created in a screen input on the flow.

The two approaches that I was thinking about are:

1) Add those 7 fields to an input screen that are needed to create one record and loop through this logic based on the user input on the number of records creation
For instance, If Start and End Dates are the fields that are going to be different for 5 records, then Start and End dates are captured for each record by looping through Screen Input 5 times

2) Seek input for each field in each screen and map those field inputs appropriately (Willing to add the dynamic behavior using Lightning)
For instance, using the above example, display Start Date in a screen with 5 different inputs, capture the values, and display End Date in a screen with 5 inputs and capture the values

So, I'm trying to understand which would be a better User experience. I'm requesting recommendations on the proposed approaches or suggestions for any other approach.

Requesting you to consider displaying validation messages, bulkifying, etc while thinking about the experience.

It will be very helpful if you can point me towards any best practices.